# Trying to implement Signup with Facebook function in my App

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-login

I have a custom button for users to register with Facebook. However when I test it is shows that I have authorized the app, but it stays on the safari page and does not return to my app. Here is what my code looks like so far.

```
@IBAction func facebookButtonWasHit(sender: AnyObject) {
        let permissions = [ "public_profile", "email" ]

        FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions(permissions, fromViewController: nil, handler: { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                self.presentViewController(UIAlertController(title: "Whoops!", message: error!.localizedDescription), animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
            else if result.isCancelled {
                self.presentViewController(UIAlertController(title: "Whoops!", message: "We couldn't access facebook! Did you hit cancel?"), animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else {

                if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) == nil){
                    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters:["fields":"email,name"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            self.presentViewController(UIAlertController(title: "Whoops!", message: error!.localizedDescription), animated: true, completion: nil)
                        } else {
                            if let loginResult = result as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                    if let emailID = loginResult["email"] as? String{
                                        self.emailTextField.text = emailID
                                    }
                                    self.nameTextField.text = loginResult["name"] as? String
                                    let userID = loginResult["id"] as! String
                                    let facebookProfileUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(userID)/picture?type=large"
                                    let url = NSURL(string:facebookProfileUrl)
                                    self.picChanged = true
                                    self.downloadImage(url!)
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    })

                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Give a screenshot at `shows that I have authorized the app`

Comment: Sounds like you're missing step 6 from this doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started